# What C# template should I use to build a server for an XNA game?

Tags: c#, networking, xna

I am going to attempt to build multiplayer into my XNA game and build a server for it at the same time, but I don't know what format the server is suppose to be in.

In most games where ever there is some player hosting, the server is invisible, it does not have it's own window, you simply create a lobby inside your game and there is a sever thread running in the background for you.

Something like that description is what I think I want, but what is the best way to develop this? Should I start the server as a console application, and then somehow figure out a way to start the console and make it invisible when a player creates a lobby, or figure out a way to port the code to a thread within the xna game? Should I use a windows form application template? What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Have you checked the XNA networking capabilities? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975801.aspx

Comment: I was going to use sockets since I don't want to be limited to live accounts

Comment: You could take a look at the Lidgren C# Network

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conceptually, your server consists of:

- A set of classes that implement the server-side game logic and network infrastructure, and
- A host application, which will either be

  - A game client, or
  - A dedicated server process

With well-designed code, these two pieces are mostly orthogonal to one another--save for some minor details like logs and server administration tools.  Sockets don't care whether they're running inside of a Windows Forms application or a console application; the question is entirely irrelevant to them.

So what you really want to do is put your server classes in a **class library** project, and then reference that project from whatever applications need to host a server.  And that host application can be pretty much anything.  It can be an XNA game, if you want players to host servers through the client, or a Windows Service, if you want a dedicated server process, or something else entirely.

At that point, it's simply a matter of calling `Server.Start()` (or whatever applies in your case) from the appropriate place in the host application--for example, in a background thread.

Answer (score 1):

Terraria, which is XNA, has a console window server application and the main game. The hosting types are in-game hosting and a dedicated server. Both hosting types actually use the same server application, but whilst the dedicated server just runs the process as normal, the game client runs the console window app in hidden mode so it doesn't appear in the task bar or show as a window.

Food for thought!